# How do I fill the spider panel for HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts, spider-chart

Is it **possible** to fill those **pie** areas? If so, how?

I mean, **"A"(red)** and **"B"(purple)** and the rest all.

[image]

Comment: I think that you should be able to use another series (column or area) to meet your goal. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/juqshf75/

Comment: One point to mention: if these shaded areas are just for illustration only, meaning, the user will not be interacting with them, I'd suggest adding `showInLegend: false` and `enableMouseTracking: false`.